# Sublime change snippet 'doc[tab]'

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

when I type `doc` + `tabe` it automatically generate a baisc html structure:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I change this? I search through

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\HTML
```

But couldn't find the trigger keyword 'doc'

Comment: Maybe it's easier and faster to create a new similar Snippet (*Tools>new Snippet*) than to modify the default snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the `Emmet` package.

`Preferences -> Browse Packages` and locate `Emmet`.
Look in the `snippets.json` file.

But the advice of [sergioFC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3870761/sergiofc) is wise. Make your own snippet instead of trying to alter the default behaviour of `Emmet`